# Html/jQuery: Make div disappear and use Canvas underneath

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a canvas scratch card game and I wanted to put 'play' image over it and when its pressed the image should disappear and user can start playing.

The image, with me, disappears for like 1/2 second then it comes again. This is probably some CSS magic which IM not so good at.

Any help appreciated

```
<div id="canvasImage" class="col-1-2">
  <div class="play-hover">
    <img id="img"class="img-hover"src="resource/images/play.png"
     onclick="prices()">
    </img>
  </div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $(document).on("click",function (e) {
      if (e.target.id=="img") {
        $("#canvas").fadeToggle(200);
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

  <script>
  this.go = function(data){

    $(function(){
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

      canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      var scratch_layer = new ScratchMask(canvas, "resource/images/paris.png", canvas.width, 
      canvas.height, data,
        function(){
            console.log("success2");

        }
    );

    $(".loading").remove();
  })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){$("#canvasImage").fadeOut(1500); } ,3000);
});
```

Can you please go with above solution `setTimeOut` function will automatically disappear an image based upon time you mentioned